# Is it possible to remove today's date next to date field without customization?

Tags: visualforce, force.com, date-picker

I have one Date of birth field and it is showing today's date link next to text box. Is it possible to remove without doing any customization?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a Formula field that outputs the value of your birthday field and than remove the original field from the layout.

Comment: Hi Basti can You Please explain clearly ?? Thank you

Comment: Read [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Formulas) if you need more info about formula fields.

Comment: Hi Basti I dont want to change my field type it should be date type..so Can you please??

Comment: In this case the answer is: no, you can't modify standard UI in salesforce. My approach would just be a workaround.

Comment: Hi, you can put this on your vf page and it should work.

<style type="text/css">
.dateFormat{
   visibility:hidden;
}
</style>